# Regex to match all single or double digit numbers

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need to create a regex to match all occurrences of a single or double digit (surrounded with a space on each side of the digit). I am trying with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/JOSRtG/1):

`\s\d{1,2}\s`

and I am running it on this string:

`charge to at10d to and you 12 sdf 90 fdsf fsdf32 frere89 32fdsfdsf ball for 1 8 toyota`

matches:

`' 12 ', ' 90 ', ' 1 '`

but it does not match the 8 when it is beside the 1.
Does anyone know how I can adjust the regex so I can include both these digits together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying the match both the leading and trailing space around the required number. If you just get away with one of these spaces(by using a [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) as shown below to remove the trailing space), you will get rid of the problem.

Try this regex:

`\s\d{1,2}(?=\s)`

**Explanation:**

- `\s` - matches a white-space
- `\d{1,2}` - matches a 1 or 2 digit number
- `(?=\s)` - returns the position(0-length match) which is followed by a space. So, it doesn't actually matches the space but makes sure that current position is followed by a space

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JOSRtG/3)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [word boundry](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-word-boundary) `\b` expression.

The word boundary will find numbers that are not wrapped by a letters, numbers or the underscore sign. It will catch 1 or 2 digits that are wrapped by spaces, start and end of string, and non word characters (#12@ - will get he 12).

```js
var str = "51 charge to at10d to and you 12 sdf 90 fdsf fsdf32 frere89 32fdsfdsf ball for 1 8 toyota 12";

var result = str.match(/\b\d{1,2}\b/g);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: It will also match the `12` in the string `#12@`. The OP has asked there need to spaces around the number